# How to pass values of a list or tuple separately and save them as properties of say corresponding images

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have created two list tl_list and br_list. I have some image files stored in a separate folder. I want to pass the individual elements of these lists as corresponding properties of their respective image files.

eg: The first values in tl_list and br_list should be considered for the first image the second value in tl_list and br_list should be considered for the second image and so on. Right now with my current code, I get all the values in the list passed for each image.

tl_list and br_list are the coordinates of top left and bottom right coordinates of the bounding rectangle which i am using to annotate images and save them as xml files.

My code is:
    import os
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    from generate_xml import write_xml  # Import from another script

```
# global constants
img = None
tl_list = []
br_list = []
object_list = []


# constants
image_folder = 'C:/Users/Angel of 
Darkness/Downloads/Desktop/Thesis/videos/1_05/frames'
savedir = 'annotations'
obj = 'red_hat'

#extract and manipulate values from CVS file containing center coordinates of each object of interest
def b_box():
    global tl_list
    global br_list
    global object_list
    global img
    df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv') 
    tl_x = df.iloc[5:30, 0:1] - 30    #manipulate to get top left x coordinate
    tl_y = df.iloc[5:30, 1:2] - 30    #manipulate to get top left y coordinate
    br_x = df.iloc[5:30, 0:1] + 30    #manipulate to get bottom right x coordinate
    br_y = df.iloc[5:30, 1:2] + 30    #manipulate to get bottom right y coordinate
    tl_x = (tl_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    tl_y = (tl_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    br_x = (br_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    br_y = (br_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    tl_list.append((tl_x, tl_y))    #store tl values in a list
    br_list.append((br_x, br_y))    #store br values in a list
    object_list.append(obj)         #store object in a list


#loop over images  in a folder and write XML file using values from the list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n, image_file in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):
        img = image_file
        image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        b_box()
        for tl in tl_list:
           for br in br_list:
                write_xml(image_folder, img, object_list, tl, br_list, 
savedir)   # Import from another script
                tl_list = []
                br_list = []
                object_list = []
                img = None
```

So as I said I want to pass first values(tl_list and br_list) for first image second values(tl_list and br_list) for the second image and so on. Right now all values(tl_list and br_list) are passed for each image. Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use return values whenever you can to reduce the risk of overwriting other important global variables. This being said, the following code should do the trick (untested):

```
# constants
image_folder = 'C:/Users/Angel of 
Darkness/Downloads/Desktop/Thesis/videos/1_05/frames'
savedir = 'annotations'
obj = 'red_hat'

#extract and manipulate values from CVS file containing center coordinates of each object of interest
def b_box():
    df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv') 
    tl_x = df.iloc[5:30, 0:1] - 30    #manipulate to get top left x coordinate
    tl_y = df.iloc[5:30, 1:2] - 30    #manipulate to get top left y coordinate
    br_x = df.iloc[5:30, 0:1] + 30    #manipulate to get bottom right x coordinate
    br_y = df.iloc[5:30, 1:2] + 30    #manipulate to get bottom right y coordinate
    tl_x = (tl_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    tl_y = (tl_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    br_x = (br_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    br_y = (br_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
    tl_list=[zip(tl_x, tl_y)]          #store tl values in a list
    br_list=[zip(br_x, br_y)]          #store br values in a list
    #object_list=[obj]                  # I have no idea, why you would want to store the object in a list
    return tl_list,br_list,obj


#loop over images  in folder and write xml file using values from list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i, img in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):
        image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        tl_list,br_list,obj = b_box()
        write_xml(image_folder, img, object_list, tl_list[i], br_list[i], savedir)
```

Comment: hey, thanks so much for your reply. I tried it but i get the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Annotations.py", line 46, in <module>
    tl_list,br_list,obj = b_box()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: I made a small mistake in the return statement which I corrected. If the problem persists, could you please provide a full call stack? To know that the b_box function fails is not very helpful. As I have no access to your input files, examples for tl_x, tl_y, br_x and br_y would also help a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i got busy. But thanks this code works

Answer (score -1):

list indexes. Access the values in the list with a position. Position 0 will give the first value. Position 1 will give the second value in the lists.

See below for a minimal example

```
i = 0

list1 = [0,0,0,0,0]
list2 = [0,0,0,0,0]

while i < len(list1) and i < len(list2):
    list1pos = list1[i]
    list2pos = list2[i]

    #Use list1pos and list2pos as needed
    i = i +1
```